# The code should be able to add text when clicked "pievienot" but its not working like a button. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa2hE.png-should look like

Tags: php, html, css, json

```
<?
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);

if(!is_array($data)){
    $data = [
        'items' => []
    ];
}

if(count($_POST) > 0) {
    
    if(isset($_POST["addNew"]) && !empty($_POST["addNew"])) {
        $data['items'] [] = [
            'text' => $_POST['addNew'],
            'done' => false,
            'date' => date["j.m.Y G:i:s"]
        ];
    }

    if(isset($_POST["editId"])) {
        $id = $_POST['editId'];

        if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
            unset($data['items'] [$id]);
        } else {
            $data['items'] [$id] ['done'] = isset($_POST['done']);
        }
    }

    file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

    header('Location .');

    die();

}

?>
<style>
body {
  background-image: url('yes.jpg');
}
</style>
<html >
<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightgreen" >
</body>
</html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>lol</title>
        <meta http-equiv="COntent-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <? foreach($data['items']as $index => $item) { ?>
            <li>
                <form method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="editId" value="<?=$index?>"/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="done" onchange="this.form.submit()" <?=($item['done'] ? 'checked ="checked"' : '')?>/>
                    <?=(isset($item['date']) ? $itemp['date'] .' :: ' : '') .' ' .$item['text']?>
                    <button name="delete">Dzēst</button>
        </form>
        </li>
        <? } ?>
        </ul>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="adNew" placeholder="Pievienot uzdevumu..." autofocus/>
            <input type="sumbit" value="Pievienot"/>
        </form>
        </html>
        </body>

        }
```

The code should be able to add text when clicked "pievienot" but its not working like a button...It should be working like a bookmark,i can add something,and check the time and date when i added it.
Would be really grateful if someone could explain whats wrong...Theres also a .json file but there isnt anything useful
{
"items":
{
"text": "tris cetri",
"done":false
},
{
"text": "tris cetri",
"done":false

```
},
{
    "text":"tris cetri",
    "done": true
},
{
    "text": "vienk\u0101r\u016li uzdevumi katram pr\u0101tam",
    "done"`enter code here`:false,
    "date": "6.04.2022 10:08"
}

|
```

}

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["addNew"])` - there is no form field with that name anywhere. `<input type="text" name="adNew"` - check your spelling.

Comment: Check your HTML elements, multiple `<html>` and `<body>` tags, and closing them in the wrong order